# Why does HX711 load cell amp not have an I2C address?

Tags: adc, i2c, load, load-cell

Context: I am trying hook up the TI CC26X2R1 dev board to a 5 wire load cell to act as an end device in a Thread network. I use the Sparkfun HX711 load cell amp to amp and as an ADC (links for both below).

Question: the I2C address is a required parameter for setting up I2C on the CC26X2R1, but I am not able to get the I2C address of the Sparkfun Hx711 using any of the standard I2C scanner programs for Arduino. Am I missing something? Shouldn't the HX711 have an I2C address?

If not apparent already, I am relatively new to this, so thanks in advance!

[Load cell](https://www.omega.com/en-us/force-strain-measurement/load-cells/lc103b/p/LCM103B-50)
[CC26X2R1](https://www.ti.com/tool/LAUNCHXL-CC26X2R1)
[Sparkfun HX711](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide/all)

Answer (score 3):

The HX711 doesn't have an I2C interface. No interface, no address.

It has a serial interface, that can be read as SPI.

As very few bits need to be programmed, it doesn't have a data line going to the HX711, it instead counts the clock pulses used to read the data out, and switches inputs based on the number received. A clever trick, which saves a package pin.